# Moving to new composer.json with web directory

Tags: migrations

In my Drupal 8.8.2 site, all my images were in public_html/sites/default/files. But in the new scheme of things, the sites directory is under public_html/web/sites/default/files, and every link is broken.
Is there a way to fix this en masse?

Comment: Can you confirm the HTTP response for those links?  For example, it's possible the links are there but you're hitting a permissions issue.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. If you moved the webroot from `public_html` to `public_html/web`, all those links are still valid (because the path relative to the webroot is still the same).

Comment: When you access the site, do you always have to type in the `/web` part in the URL?

Comment: The links are public_html/sites/default/files* and they need to be  public_html/web/sites/default/files*. And yes, I need to type in web on my URLs. I do not have any RewriteBase active, and there is no .htaccess in public_html. This setup is on my home Linux machine where I have many sites on a single port, so I need prefaces in my addresses, i.e., https://jarfx.dyndns.org/jar/drupal/web

Comment: Are you referring to images placed with CKEditor?

Comment: Yes. I use IMCE too